# Flatten nested JSON second level only

Tags: javascript, json, flatten

I have my JSON structured like this

```
var data = var data = [{"id": 451, "title": {    "rendered": "title1" }, "acf": {    "floor": "6",    "business": [       "business"    ],    "status": {       "value": "null",       "label": "Määramata"    },    "suund": "",    "area": {       "value": "full",       "label": "Terve korrus"       },       "suurus": "",       "tookohad": "",    }, },];
```

I need to flatten acf to get it like this without acf nesting.

```
var data = [
  {
"id": 451,
"title": {
   "rendered": "Title 1"
},
   "floor": "6",
   "business": [
      "business"
   ],
   "status": {
      "value": "null",
      "label": "Määramata"
   },
   "suund": "",
   "area": {
      "value": "full",
      "label": "Full"
      },
      "size": "",
},
];
```

I tried to use this function

```
function flat(source, target) {
Object.keys(source).forEach(function (k) {
    if (source[k]!== null && typeof source[k] === 'object') {
        flat(source[k], target);
        return;
    }
    target[k] = source[k];
});flatObject = {};flat(data, flatObject);console.log(flatObject);
```

But it flattens everything. I need to pick stuff out of acf but keep elements with id separate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand what you want to achieve is this:
( I improved the example so that you can work even on an array of objects )

```js
var data = [{"id": 451, "title": {    "rendered": "title1" }, "acf": {    "floor": "6",    "business": [       "business"    ],    "status": {       "value": "null",       "label": "Määramata"    },    "suund": "",    "area": {       "value": "full",       "label": "Terve korrus"       },       "suurus": "",       "tookohad": "",    }, },]; 

function flat(source) {
  let result = source.map(el => {
    let noAcf = {}
    Object.keys(el).forEach(key => {
      if(key === "acf"){
        noAcf = {...noAcf, ...el[key]}
      } else {
        noAcf[key]=el[key]
      }
    })
    return noAcf
  })
  return result
}


const flatObjectsList = flat(data);
console.log(flatObjectsList);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
const flattenData = {
  ...data,
  acf: undefined,
  ...data.acf
};
delete flattenData['acf'];
```

This method chains some [destructuring assignments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment). First - the `...data` - we copy all the data in the first level. Then in the new object we overwrite `acf` with `undefined`. This reduces the memory footprint. At last we overwrite/copy the complete object of `data.acf`, thus flatten the array in the way you want.

If you can live with the `acf: undefined` in the array, you can remove the `delete flattenData['acf']` and make it a bit faster.